# What does -attr (*, "datatypes) mean?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to parse down a big DBF into something smaller that I can work with but I can't convert or read into a CSV. When you look at the bottom I see something labeled " -attr (*, "datatypes)" that I suspect is the issue since the other data sets I'm working with are formatted similarly but don't have this. Does anyone know what this thing is?

[image]

Comment: What does `str(Nassau_data)` return? What if you convert it to a data frame using `as.data.frame()`?

Comment: You can safely ignore these, they are FYI "attributes" meta-data that might be added eg if you used `read_csv` and some of the column types were guessed. To remove them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000753/remove-attributes-from-data-read-in-readrread-csv

Comment: Where do you see str(Nassa_data)?  I only see chr and factors here. To clarify though Nassau_data is a data frame in this situation. Also will the read_csv function work if this is a tibble?

Comment: Also @JonSpring

Comment: Also just curious why do these populate if I didn't select these attributes? Could I use the select function to remove them?

Comment: You haven't given any information about how you loaded these, so it will be hard to offer much insight to what happened. But if for example you used `read_csv` there's a step where it guesses your data types and records those to an attribute, see link in my prior comment.